# Pure JavaScript async/await in a while loop waiting on each XMLHttpRequest to complete before sending the next XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to update a project from a couple years ago with an async/await piece.  I don't think this is the correct way to write it today (fetch, etc), but it has been written this way?  This is behind a firewall.  When the HTML button is pressed the function btnCurrent2Machine is called.  I have really struggled with this piece.  This code does not show any of my attempts at the async/await.  However, I have made tons of attempts.  Thanks.

```
// Function to make a XMLHttpRequest to transfer a recipe
// from a central host to a particular machine
function btnCurrent2Machine( tool )
{
  // Defines variable to hold "select" element
  var valuesCurrent = document.getElementById( "valuesCurrent" );

  // If nothing selected give error
  if( valuesCurrent.selectedIndex == -1 )
  {
    window.alert( "You must first select item(s) from the \"Current\" pane." )
  }
  else
  {
    // Loop through all options
    for( var option = 0; option < valuesCurrent.length; option++ )
    {
      if( valuesCurrent[option].selected == true )
      {
        // Option was selected
        (function (optionValue)
        {
          // Setup request
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest( );

          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function( )
          {
            if( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200 )
            {
              // Response is back from server
              if( xhttp.responseText == "" )
              {
                // Response is good
                // Find index
                var i = 0;
                for( i = 0; i < valuesCurrent.length; i++ )
                {
                  if( optionValue == valuesCurrent[i].value )
                  {
                    indexCurrent = i;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                // Find index
                var indexMachine = 0;
                for( i = 0; i < valuesMachine.length; i++ )
                {
                  if( optionValue == valuesMachine[i].value )
                  {
                    indexMachine = i;
                    break;
                  }
                }

                // If not already in select for that machine create option for recipe
                if( !indexMachine )
                {
                  var optionClone = valuesCurrent[indexCurrent].cloneNode( true );

                  valuesMachine.appendChild( optionClone );
                }

                // Show in message that recipe transferred.
                // Above the option was appended to the bottom of the list
                document.getElementById( "statusMachine" ).innerHTML = valuesCurrent[indexCurrent].value;
              }
              else
              {
                // Display error message from server
                alert( xhttp.responseText );
                return 1;
              }
            }
          };

          // Open/send call to server
          xhttp.open( "GET", "current2machine.php?tool=" + tool + "&recipe=" + valuesCurrent[option].value, true );
          xhttp.send( );
        })(valuesCurrent[option].value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use async/await directly with XmlHttpRequest. async/await only works with things that return Promises, and that doesn't. You'll need to switch to using fetch. (You could, alternatively, wrap a bunch of XHR code in your own constructed Promises, but trust me, using fetch instead is a much easier solution.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Sorry it took me so long.  Our shop blew up right after I posted this.